# SoftEther VPN vs OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm currently using OpenVPN, and it's too slow. Searching for alternatives, I've found https://www.softether.org/ which claims to be much faster than OpenVPN.

Can anyone approve this?

Are there any insights regarding SoftEther VPN stability (it is a new project, after all)?

EDIT:

The network setup is quite simple - 1 physical host (CentOS6), with 3 virtual guests (CentOS6, using KVM/libvirt). One of the guests is the OpenVPN server. Its 'tap0' device is bridges with (the virutalized) 'eth0' device.

Saying "too slow" is compared to accessing the same machine with SSH. When accessing the guest with SSH and X Forwarding (with reverse tunneling, without the OpenVPN), the graphics response is reasonable. When accessing it with OpenVPN, it gets toooo slow.

Comment: What is your use case? Clarify what you mean by OpenVPN being too slow. I have never in my life encountered VPN software where the software itself was the bottleneck - the bottleneck is nearly always the network connection.

Comment: In my experience, OpenVPN is relatively fast.  Though the specific config matters.  Use udp, not tcp.  Routed, not bridged mode.  Perform some test and try alternate encryption ciphers.

Comment: To salvage this question from being closed, perhaps you ought to edit it and turn it into more of a "This is how I have OpenVPN configured, but I'm seeing X behavior. What can I do to increase performance?" sort of affair. *That* would be an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you will get a noticeable improvement by using SoftVPN (not that I've used it, its just that OpenVPN is pretty efficient).

I suspect the issue you are having is related to compression.  SSH may be automatically compressing your data where OpenVPN isn't configured to - compression makes a huge difference on X forwarding.   To fix this, you can simply enable compression in OpenVPN by adding the switch --comp-lzo